# How to prove the existence of bijectivity?

Tags: functions, projective-geometry

Cordial greeting.

I recently came across an exercise that asks me to demonstrate bijectivity between two lines in a projective plane.

But firstly, I would like to know how bijectivity is demonstrated to apply it to that topic.

I would be very grateful for any contribution or guide that you give me, thank you from beforehand.

my question is given based on this exercise:

> In a projective plane: Given two different lines $L$ and $M$, there is a bijection $f: L \to M.$

Comment: can we represent the lines in eqn form?

Comment: It might be the language barrier, but it sounds like you want to know what a bijection is. A bijection between two sets $A$ and $B$ is a function $f : A \to B$ that is both injective and surjective (we say the function $f$ is a "bijection", or that $f$ is "bijective"). Are you familiar with injectivity and surjectivity?

Comment: Yes, I understand how the injective and surjective functions work but I don't know how to apply it in the projective planes and how to work it.

Comment: @itzner Ah, OK then, here's a hint: construct the bijection using a family of lines $\mathcal{F}$ not including $L$ or $M$. Given a line $N \in \mathcal{F}$, map the intersection of $N$ and $L$ to the intersection of $N$ and $M$. Think about what properties $\mathcal{F}$ needs to have in order to make this a well-defined function with a well-defined inverse function.